# How does Boss HP scaling in flexible raids work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the raid difficulties "Normal" and "Heroic" a flexible number of players are possible, anywhere between 10 and 30. I noticed the HP of the Boss seems to scale roughly linearly, but not exactly. Is there a precise formula known?

What about the incoming damage? Is it constant or does it scale as well?

Comment: You could always try making a formula if you are in a large enough guild? Check HP at 10,11...30 people then find the ax+by=c formula

Comment: I don't know if individual abilities scale in damage, but do remember that as you add more people to your raid, more people are taking damage from the raid AoE abilities, so overall there is more to heal.

Comment: @Grohlier My hope is that someone already has done it.

Comment: I can only answer partially. The Damage done by the boss didn't scale with the number of players (but obviously with the difficulty). Blizzard tried this earlier but this lead to to much dmg on the Tanks which most likely results in whipes. But as @Troyen says the dmg rises implicitly due to AoE abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is better served as a comment since I haven't found anything authoritative, but the closest information I've uncovered is:

1. Anecdotally, from [this thread](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/13123845500), some players report that each new person adds ~4M HP to the boss. (Brackenspore, in this case; it may vary by boss.)
2. [This page](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Flexible_Raid) has a copy of a blue post (and a link to [the original](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/10585638963?page=4#77)) indicating that boss **abilities** (not HP) are probabilistic added based on the number of raid members. It also includes the information that boss HP scales more slowly than player damage, fwiw. (Do note that this post is 1+ year old and the information may have changed.)

Comment: If you read the original it doesn't state anything about HP not being added.  It states that it scales slowly.  Watcher then goes on to state that an 18-player raid with 12 damage-dealers will kill a boss slightly faster than a 10-player raid with 6 damage-dealers.  This would be dramatically faster if the boss HP didn't scale.

Comment: Read all of the original: he says, "...since boss health and damage scale up more slowly than does raid throughput."