# What is the scaling of health on a boss per person in normal/heroic raiding in world of warcraft

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to calculate the required DPS on bosses based on the boss' HP.  Now obviously this scales dependant on the size of the raids.

For example The Butcher on Heroic mode apparently has 66,080,000 HP according to [wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=77404/the-butcher). The issue here is that it doesn't state what raid size he has this health at.

It would be nice to understand the algorithm behind the scaling in order to calculate what health the boss would have at any given raid size.

Comment: That's where I got the 66 million from. that doesn't state at what raid size he has 66 million at.

Comment: Good question, but appears to be essentially a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196747/how-does-boss-hp-scaling-in-flexible-raids-work

Comment: Very Interesting question but far too broad to answer. The bosses  HP doesn't just go up by x% for every additional player. It's calculated individually for every boss depending on the bosses mechanics.

Comment: @Lin Indeed it may be similar, but that question hasn't got an answer.

Comment: @Jutschge the closest I have got it is 111.7M health with 25 people for the butcher, 134.04M for 30 people. ((111.7M / 25) * 30 = 134.04M) but it's not exact as you can see.

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman Yes, but I'm adding an 'answer' (such as it is) now. :)

Comment: By the way The Health Numbers on WoWhead seem to be for 15 man groups. I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: @Jutschge using my formula ((111.7M / 25) * 15 = 67,020,000) so yeah, it seems like it is around 15 players.

Comment: I can understand closing it as a duplicate, but why is this being closed as too broad?  It's definitely answerable by a single, reasonably-small answer.  "It's too hard for me to figure out" does not make it too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact figure, but working it out based on the figure of a 25 man raid he has 111,700,000 health and 134,300,000 in 30 man raid.

```
(111.7 / 25 = 4.468 * 30 = 134.04)
```

That's the closest I can get it.

Giving wowhead gives us the health for a 15 man raid we can then use this data to adjust the formula accordingly.

```
(h / 15 = 4.403r * n) = scaled_health
```